# Same margins when specifying "twoside" in memoir?

Tags: margins, memoir, double-sided

I'm using the `memoir` document class with options `openright` and `twoside`. However, as the document will be printed on regular paper instead of being binded into a book, I wish the left and right margins to be the same (while still opening chapers and parts on odd-numbered pages).

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest way is to set the horizontal margin ratio to 1:1 and let `memoir` recalculate and apply it:

```
\setlrmargins{*}{*}{1}
\checkandfixthelayout
```

The arguments to `\setlrmargins` are spine margin, fore-edge margin, and ratio, if you omit a value by writing just`*` it will be calculated.

If you don't like to use `memoir` commands the specify page dimensions, you can check the original code how margins are set depending on the `twoside` option. Originally it's:

```
\if@twoside
  \setlength\@tempdima       {\paperwidth}
  \addtolength\@tempdima     {-\textwidth}
  \setlength\oddsidemargin   {.4\@tempdima}
  \addtolength\oddsidemargin {-1in}
  \setlength\marginparwidth  {.6\@tempdima}
  \addtolength\marginparwidth{-\marginparsep}
  \addtolength\marginparwidth{-0.4in}
\else
  \setlength\@tempdima       {\paperwidth}
  \addtolength\@tempdima     {-\textwidth}
  \setlength\oddsidemargin   {.5\@tempdima}
  \addtolength\oddsidemargin {-1in}
  \setlength\marginparwidth  {.5\@tempdima}
  \addtolength\marginparwidth{-\marginparsep}
  \addtolength\marginparwidth{-0.8in} % don't know why this isn't .4
\fi
```

So, you could do the required part in your preamble:

```
\documentclass[openright,twoside]{memoir}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\makeatletter
\setlength\@tempdima       {\paperwidth}
\addtolength\@tempdima     {-\textwidth}
\setlength\oddsidemargin   {.5\@tempdima}
\addtolength\oddsidemargin {-1in}
\setlength\marginparwidth  {.5\@tempdima}
\addtolength\marginparwidth{-\marginparsep}
\addtolength\marginparwidth{-0.8in} % don't know why this isn't .4
\setlength\evensidemargin\oddsidemargin
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\blindtext[15]
\chapter{test}
\end{document}
```

I additionally set `\evensidemargin` equal to `\oddsidemargin`. With this example you will see symmetric page layout, page 4 is empty and chapter 1 starts at page 5, which is odd.

Comment: It's not that I don't like to use `memoir` commands -- it's that I don't know what they are in the first place. =) Could you please extend your answer to include the code which produces the same result but uses only `memoir` commands?

Comment: @gablin: Ok, I added the 2 commands to fix it by memoir macros.

Comment: That was much easier than what I had found. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Browsing through the manual for `memoir`, I actually found the code which does exactly what I want. In case anyone else encounters the same problem, I'll include the code here:

```
% Set margins to equal length
\newlength{\marginwidth}
\setlength{\marginwidth}{1.5in}
\setlrmarginsandblock{\marginwidth}{\marginwidth}{*} % Specify both margins
\setlrmarginsandblock{\marginwidth}{*}{1} % Specify spine & fore-edge/spine
                                          % ratio
\setlrmarginsandblock{\marginwidth}{*}{*} % Specify spine (fore-edge = spine)
\setlrmarginsandblock{*}{\marginwidth}{1} % Specify fore-edge & spine/fore-edge 
                                          % ratio
\setlrmarginsandblock{*}{\marginwidth}{*} % Specify fore-edge
                                          % (spine = fore-edge)
\checkandfixthelayout
```

Answer (score 1):

I think a simpler solution is:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
%%% set up the recto page layout
\checkandfixthelayout %or perhaps \checkandfixthelayout[lines]
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{\oddsidemargin}% after \checkandfix......
```

Source: Pg. 25 of the Memoir documentclass manual (Side margin section).

Answer (score 0):

I think the *clearest* way would be to use the `geometry` package:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[margin=2cm}{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\blindtext[15]
\chapter{test}
\end{document}
```

I had this is my document and was wondering "Why are both margins the same?"